# What is the difference between import db and import datastore

Tags: python, google-app-engine

What is the difference between import db and import datastore

```
from google.appengine.ext import db
# ore
from google.appengine.api import datastore
```

I tried to understand how to get name from a Page in the cccwiki:

```
class WikiPage(BaseRequestHandler):

    def index(name):
        # Loads the pages as index links with the given name.

        query = datastore.Query('Page')
        query['name ='] = name
        entities_list = query.Get(100)
```

Answer (score 3):

They are quite different beasts altogether.

- `google.appengine.api.datastore` is the datastore access API. It is similar to a database driver for a SQL database. It lets you connect to the datastore and run queries.
- `google.appengine.ext.db` is a data modeling API. It let's you model the data you are going to store in the datastore. It is similar to SQLAlchemy and Django's data modeling layers. It let's you express the data you need in your application in terms that make it easy to translate manipulations to queries to the datastore.

In other words, with `google.appengine.ext.db` you create a model, and manipulating that model (adding and removing entities, changing attributes of those entities) results in queries to the underlying datastore, using `google.appengine.api.datastore`.

Your `WikiPage` code doesn't use a model; it queries the datastore directly. I believe that the `cccwiki` does have it's own `Page` class, and you can create those with the `name` parameter and the data returned from the query:

```
page = Page(name, entities_list[0])
```

each entry in the `entities_list` result set is a dictionary in any case, and the contents depend on the code that *stored* stuff in the records in the first place. In the case of the `cccwiki` code I'd expect to see `content`, `user`, `created` and `modified` keys.

If you *do* have a `Page` class defined using the `google.appengine.ext.db` API, then use that to query your pages instead:

```
q = Page.all()
q.filter('name = ', name)
page = q.get()
```

and then you can access the attributes of the result.

Comment: tl;dr: `api.datastore` is low level, not publicly documented, and you shouldn't use it unless you really know what you're doing.